# Removing an element from an array (PHP)

Tags: php

I want to remove an element from a PHP array (and shrink the array size). Just looking at the PHP docs, it seems this can be done using array_slice() and array_merge()

so I am guessing (off the top of my head) that some combination of array_merge() and array_slice will work. However, array_slice() requires an index (not a key), so I'm not sure how to quickly cobble these functions together for a solution.

Has anyone implemented such a function before?. I'm sure it must be only a few lines long, but I cant somehow get my head around it (its been one of those days) ...

Actually, I just came up with this cheesy hack when writing up this question....

```
function remove_from_array(array $in, value) {
   return array_diff($in, (array)$value);
}
```

too ugly? or will it work (without any shocking side effects)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality already exists; take a look at `unset`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

```
$a = array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'gork');
unset($a['bar']);
print_r($a);
```

output will be:

```
array(
[foo] => bar
)
```

Comment: what if it's indexed by numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There's the [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function that uses a callback function to select only wanted values from the array.

Answer (score 1):

you want an unset by value. loop through the array and unset the key by value.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value == "" || $value == " " || is_null($value)) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}

/*
and if you want to create a new array with the keys reordered accordingly...
*/
$new_array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: FYI - Your if statement can be improved a bit if you would use php's empty() functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($my_array['element']);
```

Won't work?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Jack Why do you think it is a comment?

Comment: Because it looks like one? Surely you could have spent a few more seconds to make it a proper answer.

Comment: AFAIK it answers the question fully and correctly, no need to add extra garbage to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be replaced by single array_filter($arr) call